# Sending values to a custom controller wrapper

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I am attempting to pass value from an inputField to a custom controller Wrapper, and my values are coming across null ('Attempt to de-reference a null object'),  When I try to assign them to my wrapper does anyone see any issues with what I'm doing?

```
public TripProfileWrapper tripWrapper {get;set;}
```

Build the Trip

```
tripWrapper = new TripProfileWrapper();
                            trip.Name = tripName;
                            trip.Trip__c = tripWrapper.usersTrip.Trip__c;
                            trip.Contact__c =           tripWrapper.tripMember.Contact__c;
                            trip.TotalNumberofAdults__c = numberofAdults;
                            trip.TotalNumberofChildren__c =   numberOfChildern;
                            trip.UserDC__c =    tripWrapper.dcUserContact.OwnerID;
                            trip.UserPlanner__c =    tripWrapper.dcPlannerContact.OwnerId;
                            trip.NumberofPassengers__c = numberOfPassengers;
                            trip.TransportationRequested__c =   transportationRequestedCheckbox;
                            trip.SpecialAmenitiesCheckbox__c =    specialAmenitiesCheckbox;  
insert trip;
```

Wrapper

```
   public class TripProfileWrapper
    {
            public Contact dcUserContact {get;set;}
            public Contact dcPlannerContact {get;set;}
            public TripProfile__c tripMember {get;set;}
            public TripProfile__c usersTrip {get;set;}

            public TripProfileWrapper()
            {
                    dcUserContact = new Contact();
                    dcPlannerContact = new Contact();
                    tripMember = new TripProfile__c();
                    usersTrip = new TripProfile__c();
            }

    }
```

VF Page

```
<apex:inputField label="Destination Concierge" id="dcUserContact" value="{!tripWrapper.dcUserContact.OwnerID}" required="false"/>      
<apex:inputField label="Trip" id="usersTrip" value="{!tripWrapper.usersTrip.Trip__c}" required="true"/>      
 <apex:inputField label="Destination Planner" id="destPID" value="{!tripWrapper.dcPlannerContact.OwnerId}" required="false"/>  
  <apex:inputField label="Member" value="{!tripWrapper.tripMember.Contact__c}" required="false"/>
```

Comment: Can you update with where the following data is being populated: tripWrapper.tripMember.Contact__c;

Comment: `tripWrapper.tripMember.Contact__c;` Gets sent to my wrapper, and from there it gets assigned to `my trip.Contact__c`, it gets populated on my vf page (inputfield)

Comment: What line do you error on? In your second block it seems you instantiate tripWrapper but then assign values to trip ...... Just failing to figure out the actual flow.

Comment: `trip.Trip__c = tripWrapper.usersTrip.Trip__c;` is failing

Comment: Fixed, stupid mistake..

Comment: Glad you found it! Maybe post the answer for others?

Comment: I wasn't calling my init in my vf page action where I am instantiating my wrapper = s